# Disqus API 400 Error only on Production

Tags: ajax, rest, disqus

Im using the Disqus comment system and user a small client side javascript to call their rest API and check the number of posts of a given array of URLs. (Below)

The script is running fine on my local machine, however when I move it to my remote server it returns a 400 Bad Request.

Now the strange thing is if I check the request that the very same page tries to send using chrome tools, and paste it into my address bar it works!

Im node/express, the same servers locally and in production.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     var disqusPublicKey = "xxx";
     var disqusShortname = "YYY"; 
            var urlArray = [];
            $('.count-comments').each(function () {
                var url = $(this).attr('data-disqus-url');
                urlArray.push('link:' + url.replace(/\s/g,"%20"));
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: "https://disqus.com/api/3.0/threads/set.jsonp",
                data: { api_key: disqusPublicKey, forum : disqusShortname, thread : urlArray },
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function (result) {
                    Do Something
                }
            });
        });
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you update the list of authorized domains at http://disqus.com/api/applications/ ?

Comment: Spot on. My domain was down as the website of the application but not the trusted domain. Thanks!

Comment: That was the problem I faced too. Thank you very much.